# Populate one fieled when other related field is entered

Tags: javascript, php, html, database

I have two fields in my database
Roll No and Name
I have designed a html form where there are two input types
One --> "Roll No"
and other is "Name"

i want when i enter the roll number in the roll number field and press tab the name field should fill up automatically fetched from the data base.

My codes are here

***index.php***

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
var searchTimeout; //Timer to wait a little before fetching the data
$("#roll").keyup(function() {
    searchKey = this.value;

    clearTimeout(searchTimeout);

    searchTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        getUsers(searchKey);    
    }, 400); //If the key isn't pressed 400 ms, we fetch the data
});

function getUsers (searchKey) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getUser.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {value: searchKey},
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.status) {
                $("#name").val(data.userData.name);
            } else {
                // Some code to run when nothing is found
            }   
        }
    });         
}
</script>
</head>             

<table>
<tr>
    <td>Roll</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="roll" id="roll" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</html>
```

***getUser.php***

```
<?php
include "db.php";

$response = Array();

$response['status'] = false;

$query = mysql_query("SELECT `name` FROM `tab` WHERE `roll` LIKE '%".$_POST['value']."%' LIMIT 1"); //Or you can use = instead of LIKE if you need a more strickt search

if(mysql_num_rows($query)) {
    $userData = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

    $response['userData'] = $userData;
    $response['status'] = true;            
}

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: sounds like a job for AJAX

Comment: But How ? how can i do this

Comment: to broad, you need to do some work make an attempt, if\when you hit a problem ask with *code*

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `ajax`.`Ajax` communicate with `PHP` in real time,so name field would be filled automatically without pressing submit button.

`XMLHttpRequest()` is the function that would be needed to do this task.Please do some research about `XMLHttpRequest()`,which will help you to get better idea.

```
function auto(roll){
  var roll=roll;
  var ajax=new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajax.open("post","yourfile.php",true);       
  ajax.setRequestHeader("content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  ajax.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200){
      document.getElementById(Name).value=ajax.responseText;  //This line will fill the Name field automatically
     }
  }

  ajax.send("roll_num="+roll);
}
```

So,in your php file `yourfile.php` in this case,fetch `name` for that `roll`. `echo` that `name` in php file,and that `name` value will pass to ajax `asynchronously`.Then the `name` field will be populated automatically

This is how you get your expected result.